# Flutter: GoRouter slide transition direction

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, gorouter, page-transition

I make `GoRouter` work with slide transitions. I want the transition to slide from right to left when the router makes `push` and left to right when the router `pops`.

Here is the working code:

*transition_factory.dart*

```
static CustomTransitionPage getSlideTransitionPage(
  {required BuildContext context,
  required GoRouterState state,
  required Widget child,
  required bool leftToRight}) {
return CustomTransitionPage(
  key: state.pageKey,
  child: child,
  transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
      SlideTransition(
          position: animation.drive(
            Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(0.75, 0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn)),
          ),
         // textDirection:
          //    leftToRight ? TextDirection.ltr : TextDirection.rtl,
          child: child),
);

}
static Page<dynamic> Function (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) getSlidePageBuilder(
  {
  required Widget child,
  required bool leftToRight}) {
return (context, state) => TransitionFactory.getSlideTransitionPage(
    context: context, state: state, child: child, /*leftToRight: leftToRight*/);
}
```

*router.dart*

```
GoRoute(
    path: "/",
    pageBuilder: TransitionFactory.getSlidePageBuilder(
        child: const Home(), /*leftToRight: !Router.goingBack*/),

GoRoute(
    path: "/menu",
    //builder: (context, state) => const Menu(),
    pageBuilder: TransitionFactory.getSlidePageBuilder(
        child: const Menu(), /*leftToRight: !Router.goingBack*/),
```

First, I tried to change the transition direction myself by changing the `TextDirection` property, but then, at some point, I realized that code works as needed by default.

When going from Home to Menu i.e. `push` the transition is right to left. When going back from Menu to Home using `pop` the transition is left to right.

This is exactly what I want but I don't understand **Why**? What makes it work like this? I cannot see something about this in any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of how it works:

**Pushing a new route**:
Animation value goes from 0 to 1.
SlideTransition's position property is driven by a Tween that goes from Offset(0.75, 0) to Offset.zero. As a result, the transition appears to slide from right to left.

**Popping a route:**
Animation value goes from 1 to 0.
The Tween now drives the SlideTransition's position property from Offset.zero back to Offset(0.75, 0). As a result, the transition appears to slide from left to right.